# цикл for в freemarker

Tags: html, freemarker

есть две сущности: спортсмены и их бои, нужно попарно выводить записи кто с кем дерется. Реализовал две сущности в отношении @ManyToMany
формирую список в контроллере типа: 1-2-3-4
как через freemarker выводить этот список в виде:

```
1-2
3-4
```

На данный момент у меня выводится 1-2-3-4

```
<#list fights as fight>
<#list fight.getSportsmans() as b>
    ${b.getFirstName()}
</#list>
</list>
```

Answer (score 0):

все оказалось проще)

```
<#list fights as fight>
        <#list fight.getSportsmans() as b>
            ${b.getAlias()}
        </#list>
        <div>
         </div>
    <#else>
        No fight
    </#list>
```

каждый раз, когда я получаю текущий бой, нужно было просто сделать перенос через